# Someone was abusing me in comments and now downvoted me with 86 points

Tags: support, abuse

Well, it takes a hell of a lot of efforts to give a right answer and it takes even more thought processes to give a suitable explanation of what and how you made the answer.

I woke up this morning and saw a few questions and wrote the answers to them. One got accepted and one was wrong so I deleted it. On seeing this, a user named "Dad" started abusing me in comments in **Hindi**, and I flagged it.

I went to take breakfast and saw that all my answers and questions were **downvoted**, like **86** points I have lost from the **downvotes**.

The user dad was not with 100 points so he might not had done this, but he was surely pissed on me so his **alts** (alternate accounts), which may be above 100 points, have done this.

I request moderators and system administrators to kindly rectify my points. It really feels painful.

My Stack Overflow profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4964136/vir

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So it's been like an hour or so only? Don't worry, there's an automated script that reverses voting in cases like these, but it runs every 36 hours as far as I remember. You should wait two days and if you still feel some of the serial downvotes haven't been reversed, you can flag a post for moderator attention and request further inspection.

Comment: @yuvi i am really tensed, dont make me more by saying duplicate..duplicate rather try to help me if you can.

Comment: @VIR My intention was not to make you tenser by pointing you to the duplicate, but hopefully to help you see a solution to your problem was already in place. There is nothing particularly wrong in asking a duplicate, even less since it is your first meta-post and may have not realized that searching for something like this was an option. But at the same time, both here in meta and in main marking a question as duplicate **is** helping, since it points the asker in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: Don't worry about it - you'll get the reputation back overnight when the script to reverse serial voting runs next. It'll show up as a credit in your reputation history with the title "serial voting reversed."

Comment: You did the right thing by flagging the rude comments. If you have reason to believe that someone is using an alt comment, feel free to flag for moderator intervention explaining why you think that so that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your suspicions were right: that was indeed an alt account. We've deleted that alt account and suspended the culprit. There really isn't much of a point waiting out the voting reversal script before raising a flag in situations like this since it's pretty unlikely that the abusive comments and the serial downvotes were not connected.

Comment: Sir, when my deduced point will be added back, will it be added or not?

Comment: @VIR: As mentioned, your reputation should be returned to you next time the script runs. But we'll work to make sure that you are reimbursed in any case.